# Choose specific TimeRange with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm interested in using DateRange with a time input (or TimeRange if possible).  My example: I have a dataset with trades for all of january at different times of the day. I need to visualize the trades made from 16:00 to 23:59 for all dates. Currently, I can only choose a start time and end time (of the first and last day). Anyone who know how to handle this?

Comment: maybe you can use `sliderInput()` for the specific hour and minute times. and then combine them

Comment: Combine how? I don't understand

Answer (score 3):

I would use a slider range with custom date format like this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(


    sliderInput(
        "test_input",
        label = "Select time",
        min = lubridate::origin,
        max = lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1),
        value = c(lubridate::origin, lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1)),
        step = 5 * 60,
        timeFormat = "%H:%M",
        timezone = "+0000",
        ticks = FALSE
    )


)

server <- function(input, output) {


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I have tested it now, but I receive the error

 "Error in as.POSIXlt.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt” 

Do you know anything about how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think this error can originate from the code I posted, as there is no conversion involved at all. So it must happen in some code you added. Without knowing this code I cannot say much unfortunately.

Comment: Yea thats right. Running the example without adding anything is working great, but when trying ti implement my own code it goes wrong.
column(2,
           sliderInput(
             "test_input",
             label = "Select time",
             min = lubridate::origin,
             max = lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1),
             value = c(lubridate::origin, lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1)),
             step = 5 * 60,
             timeFormat = "%H:%M",
             timezone = "+0000",
             ticks = FALSE)
    ),

Comment: # Select time range to highlight
  output$input_test_ui <- renderUI({
      input$test_input
  })

Comment: Could it be a missing package?: these are the packages, that I have loaded:
library("shiny")
library("shinyjs")
library("shinydashboard")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("magrittr")
library("jsonlite")
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")
library("httr")
library("plotly")
library("quantmod")
library("plyr")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("shinyalert")
library("writexl")
library("shinyTime")
library("comprehenr")

Comment: I would suggest creating a minimal reproducable example that shows the error and posting it as a new question, as it is really a different issue than the one this thread adresses.